# document.getElementById('textbox').value stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

my code is very simple. I want the user to be able to type in a restaurant name and have my function tell them whether that restaurant serves Coke or Pepsi products. It worked fine an hour ago, but stopped working. Now, it shows the work "Pepsi" no matter what you type in. My guess is that there is something wrong with the if statements.

```
<html>

<noscript><b><center><font size="16">This app requires JavaScript to be enabled. Enable JavaScript on your browswer to make it work.</font></center></b></noscript>

<center>
<form onsubmit="popproducts()">

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input id="textbox" type="text" style="height: 100px; width: 500px" value=""></input>
</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

</form>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">

function popproducts()
{
 if(document.getElementById('textbox').value == "Cougars" || "Kane County Cougars" || "Cougars Baseball")
 {
  document.write('<center><br><font color="#0000FF" size=20></b>Pepsi</b></font></br></center>');
  document.write('<br><br><center><form><input type="button" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></form></center></br></br>');
 }
 if(document.getElementById('textbox').value == "Burge" || "Iowa" || "University of Iowa")
 {
  document.write('<center><br><font color="#FF0000" size=20><b>Coke</b></font></br></center>');
  document.write('<br><br><center><form><input type="button" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></form></center></br></br>');
 }
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: brbrbrbrbrbrbrbrbrbrbrbrbrbrbrbr.center

Comment: `document.getElementById('textbox').value == "Cougars" || "Kane County Cougars" || "Cougars Baseball"` is always truthy

Comment: Use a switch statement brah

Comment: Use "===", instead of "==" in "if" statements since we know they are of same data type.

Answer (score 4):

It's the line:

```
if(document.getElementById('textbox').value == "Cougars" || "Kane County Cougars" || "Cougars Baseball")
```

It *should* be:

```
if(document.getElementById('textbox').value == "Cougars" || document.getElementById('textbox').value == "Kane County Cougars" || document.getElementById('textbox').value == "Cougars Baseball")
```

The first part evaluates as `true` or `false` depending on what you type, but the second and third will always evaluate as `true`.

Comment: Even better would be to store `document.getElementById('textbox').value` in a variable to reduce the need for scrolling.

Comment: True, but I was writing it this way for clarity (although, perhaps I failed :) )

Answer (score 2):

All other answers are fine but here's how I usually do it:

```
var value = document.getElementById('textbox').value;

if ( /^Cougars|Kane County Cougars|Cougars Baseball$/.test( value ) ) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue:

```
if(document.getElementById('textbox').value == "Cougars" || "Kane County Cougars" || "Cougars Baseball")
```

When you have an `if` statement with the *or* operator `||`, the praser interprets it as if it was:

```
if(doc....value == "Cougars || "Kane Country Cougars" != false...)
```

In other words, the if statement is always *true* because the string `"Kane Country Cougars"` isn't false. To fix it, you should do this:

```
var val = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
if(val == "Cougars" || val == "Kane County Cougars" || val == "Cougars Baseball")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `||` operator incorrectly. If you want to check if a value equals one of many values, you have to explicitly convey that. For example:

```
if ( a == b || a == c || a == d )
```

Doing it the other way will cause the unexpected behavior you were experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var value = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
if (value == 'Cougars' || value == 'Kane County Cougars' || value == 'Cougars Baseball')
```